# Can I splice and extend feeder wires to a barn?

Tags: electrical

Running three #4 wires 150' underground to a new barn.

I ended up 12' short of the disconnect switch. is it okay to mount a weather proof junction box on the exterior wall of the barn and then splice them to feed over to the disconnect switch.

If this is okay, how high above the ground should the junction box be?

Comment: Are you pulling individual conductors in conduit, or running UF cable?

Comment: Pulling individual conductors in conduit

Answer (score 2):

Since you are pulling in conduit, you don't need a full blown box for this job.  Simply use an appropriately sized, weatherproof conduit body (a Type C is what you want, by the way) made from the same material as your conduit.

*However*, you will need to use the 314.28(A)(2) rule that the body must be no shorter than six times the distance from the entrance to the opposite wall/exit in order to size the body correctly, as you are splicing 4AWG or larger conductors in the body.